# Is there a way to create a table AS the results from a stored procedure (structure and data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a new table based on the structure/data from a stored procedure (Written here as a parameterized query). Is there any way of doing this?

```
DECLARE @ColList VARCHAR(MAX), @SQLStatement VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @ExtraColList VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ColList = ''
SET @TableName = 'History.AccountsDefaultFields'
SET @ExtraColList = 'HistDate, HistType, HistGuid, HistID'
SELECT @ColList = @ColList + Name + ' , ' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND NOT Name IN('HistDate', 'HistType', 'HistGuid', 'HistID')
SELECT @SQLStatement = 'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@ColList,1,LEN(@ColList)-1) + @ExtraColList + ' From ' + @TableName
EXEC(@SQLStatement)
```

Above is the code which I am trying to create a new table from. This is for the purpose of reordering table structures to allow legacy stored procedures to function normally. I want to create the new table with the structure and data of the results of EXEC(@SQLStatement)

Comment: Select * into new_table  from  whatever

Comment: @Hugh This stored procedure would be creating a new table, based on the columns/column order of the returned value. It would be much simpler if I just needed the data, but this is trying to be a catch-all for several different tables which all have the same issue.

Comment: Why do you need to create a procedure that can handle any query and store the output in a table? This is like creating a method in OOP that can do inserts, updates, reads and sorts on any given object. The "one proc to rule them all" concept is going to cause you mountains of problems in the future. Why not create a process that handles each of your procs, then you can dynamically decide which one of them to call.